# How can I use an integer like a string in a SQL statement

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, nsstring

Edited, trying to explain better the context.

I want to delete a record on a SQLite DB in Xcode.

The value of the record is added as follow:

```
sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO tblTextos (\"txtMostrado\", \"txtCopiado\") VALUES(\"%@\", \"%@\")", [txt2BS stringValue], [txt2BC stringValue]];// Where txt2BS and txt2BC are  NSTextField
```

To delete the record, I'm using the next sentence:

```
sentenciaSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM tblTextos WHERE txtMostrado = '%@'", txtaborrar];  //where tblTextos  is a table, txtMostrado a field (text field) and txtaborrar a String variable (NSString).
```

The issue is when the `txtaborrar` variable has just a number inside, for instance 22. Then the sentence doesn't work and the record is not deleted. 
I tried to force the variable value to a string using things like:

```
txtaborrar = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[comboTodos stringValue]];//where Combotodos is a combo
```

But it doesn't work. If the txtaborrar value is just a number, the record is not deleted.

Unfortunately, the value of the field  can be a numeric value or text value.

Any help is more than welcome!

Comment: Thanks for editing the post. I will pay attention on your corrections for the next time

Answer (score 2):

What sort of data are you keeping in the `txtMostrado` column? Is it always numeric values? If so, you shouldn't be storing these as text representation of numbers at all. Store them actually as numeric values.

Furthermore, you should should not be building your SQL statements with `stringWithFormat` at all. You should use `?` placeholders. Thus, your SQL would be:

```
sentenciaSQL = @"DELETE FROM tblTextos WHERE txtMostrado = ?"; //where tblTextos is a table, txtMostrado a field and txtaborrar a String variable (NSString).
```

Then after you prepare your SQL statement with `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, but before you call `sqlite3_step`, you would bind your values to each of the `?` placeholders in the SQL. If this `txtMostrado` was actually an integer data type, you'd do something like:

```
sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, value);  // where `1` is the 1-based index of the occurrence of the ? in the SQL; and `value` is the int variable holding the value
```

If `txtMostrado` was a string data type, you'd do something like:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [value UTF8String], -1, NULL);  // where `1` is the 1-based index of the occurrence of the ? in the SQL; and `value` is the NSString variable holding the value
```

See [`sqlite3_bind_xxx()` documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) for more information.

This rule applies to both when inserting values as well as when supplying `where` clauses, like above.

Note, this completely eliminates the use of the quotation marks in the SQL (even when you use `sqlite_bind_text`) and solves problems that can arise when your string values, themselves, contain quotation marks. It also protects you against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: txtMostrado is not always a numeric value, it can be a numeric value or a text string.

Comment: @xur Very good, then `sqlite3_bind_text` is your friend (but likely unrelated to your immediate problem). The next thing to check is the precise contents of `txtaborrar` vs what's actually in the database. Show us what both are. Annoyingly, the presence or absence of a space or decimal point makes a big difference when dealing with strings. Unfortunately, there's not enough here to diagnose the source of the issue. You need to log these values and update your question accordingly if we're going to help you further.